# Saml with spring 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring, saml

I am newbee with SAMLv2 and I need to integrate it on my webapp (acting like SP) running under spring 2.5.6. 
All sample i could see are using spring 3 at minima, do you have example under spring 2.5.6 ?

I can't (due to time issue) migrate my SP to spring 3, any help would be very appreciated...

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several resources that you can use as references:

**Spring Security SAML Extension**

Spring SAML Extension allows seamless inclusion of SAML 2.0 Service Provider capabilities in Spring applications. All products supporting SAML 2.0 in Identity Provider mode (e.g. ADFS 2.0, Shibboleth, OpenAM/OpenSSO, Ping Federate, Okta) can be used to connect with Spring SAML Extension.

- Link: **http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/**

**Spring Boot-based sample Service Provider by using Spring Security SAML extension**

Currently Spring Security SAML module doesn't provide a starter for Spring Boot. Moreover, its configuration is XML-based as of this writing. The aim of this project is to explain how to develop a Service Provider (SP) which uses Spring Boot (1.4.0.RELEASE) and Spring Security SAML Extension (1.0.2.RELEASE), by defining an annotation-based configuration (Java Configuration). Thymeleaf is also used as template engine.

- Link:
  **https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample**

This project represents a complete implementation example of a SAML 2.0 Service Provider in Spring.

Comment: Thx for your response, but it seems spring-saml won't work under my version of spring-security. 2 options : migrate on spring3, or make an other webapp...
I'm on the way of the second option :)

Comment: Again, you could deploy a web-server (plus Shibboleth) on top of your Spring application.